Postfix - adding message-id to logs
In postfix log ther are following logs:
Jun  4 06:32:44 zcs723 postfix/cleanup[16293]: <<QUEUE_ID>>: message-id=<value_of_message_id>
Jun  4 06:32:45 zcs723 postfix/lmtp[16311]:  <<QUEUE_ID>>: to=...... status=sent (250 2.1.5 Delivery OK)

First maps message-id to queue-id
Second tells that message was delivered.
From client perspective if I want to check, if email was really delivered, I need to use both logs, first one to get queue-id and second to check status.
Is there a way to include message-id in status=sent log?
